# Database connection not configured

Tags: php, database, laravel, mamp

I am currently doing a local project, using **MAMP** with **PHP version 7.4.21** and I can't seem to run my  system because the database is not configured correctly.

Here's my **.env**

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost:8888/VMLM

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=vmlm
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

and here's my **database.php**

```
connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
        'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'vivemlm'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'admin'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'admin'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=vivemlm
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=admin
```

`DB_CONNECTION`  is the driver that you will use